# How to get current value of a bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is:

1. Select drop-down-list `drp0` first and then select `drp1`.
2. When you select `drp1`, if `drp0` has no value selected, `alert("Please select Leave Type Dropdown first")`.
3. Then set `drp1` to default value and set focus on `drp0`.

These are my two dropdowns:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Select Leave Type</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-inverse"></i>
        <button class="btn btn0 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu0" data-toggle="dropdown">
            --Select--
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-inverse0" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu0" id="drp0">
            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="casual" class="list0" href="#">Casual Leave</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="annual" class="list0" href="#">Annual Leave</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="medical" class="list0" href="#">Medical Leave</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Select Employee Name</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-inverse"></i>
        <button class="btn btn1 btn-default dropdown-toggle hide-button" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            --Select--
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-inverse1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" id="drp1">
            <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
                <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute1="${person.getId()}" class="list1" href="#">${person.getName()}</a></li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second dropdown is populating pretty well. No problem in that. 
[image]

Actually I found a way to check is dropdown1 is selected or not, While selecting dropdown2? But the problem is when dropdown1 has selected value I get this undefined error alert? 

Looks like its not taking the current value of dropdown1. 

Here is my code.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-inverse1 li > a').click(function () {
            var $person_id = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute1");
            var $leave_type = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute0");
            if (typeof $leave_type === 'undefined') {
                alert("Empty");
            } else {
                alert("Not Empty");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is I get "Empty" alert whether dropdown1 has a value or not. How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: It will be good if you post the **rendered html** instead of this. Open the browser and press `F12` and select the html from there or you can create a problem demo in jsfiddle!!

Comment: No Output!! What do you mean!! Inspect element on the dropdown and get the html!!

Comment: Are you talking about **[Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)** cs I think you need this functionality not actual dropdown!!!

Comment: Its not bootstrap dropdown!! It should be **bootstrap select** The one I linked above!! You want the value to be appeared on the select menu once selected right?

Comment: Change your logic if you're concerned about the alert... `if typeof( $leave_type !== 'undefined' ) { alert "WooHoo" };`

Comment: @Eddie No I'm not worried of alert. I'm trying to get that $leave_type's value

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2nsq5z3q/1/)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao you must be my fairy god mother (or may be father).. Thank you. It is the exactly what I need..  God bless you.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao still I need to set this with usual bootstrap dropdown.

Comment: @pippilongstocking I feel that it creates the structure you want `ul li` when it renders!! Just right click on the dropdown in the fiddle and do inspect element and see the structure!!

Comment: :( I don't see same structure.. Can you give me a screenshot. :( And I can't change this design now. :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thank you for your support..

Comment: Give me a moment!! I'l give you screenshor!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks I'm planing to use bootstrap select in in future projects..

Comment: @pippilongstocking. here you go with **[image](http://s3.postimg.org/9pa5sodcj/Untitled.png)**

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: I've changed the image to show the rendered part by the `bootstrap select` for the normal select!! Check the image now!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao why doesn't this shows in real code? I don't understand .. how this is hidden.

Comment: That's what the specialty of the jquery plugins!! they hide the real code and render the beautified one to the user but never effects functionality part of the real ones!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm gona dig deep about this. Thank you.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @pippilongstocking I've added an answer!! check and let me know!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qsL45pv4/1/)** and most simplified and better version for your solution:

```
$('.dropdown-inverse1 li > a').click(function () {
      $(".btn1").html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
$('.dropdown-inverse2 li > a').click(function (e) {
     var s = $(".btn1").text().trim();
     if(s=="Button1"){
        alert("Empty");
        $(".btn2").html('Button2  <span class="caret"></span>');
        setTimeout(function(){
             $(".btn1").trigger('click');
        },100); //set a timeout of 100ms to trigger the click so as to open the required dropdown
          return;
     } 
     $(".btn2").html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

You had some problems in your solution like once you select `dropdown` the `caret` i.e. arrow used to get replaced since you were replacing `text` of `.btn1`. Now it will replace with `caret` and content as `html`. Hope it helps.

Comment: in   setTimeout(function(){
             $(".btn1").trigger('click');
        },100); meaning is when second dropdown click it takes 100ms  to check the condition and whether or not show the alert? Should we do this often in jquery?

Comment: No. Its like give a 100 ms gap for next event to occur!! This is useful when you have multiple events occurring at the same time!

Comment: multiple events means dropdown2 selection and search dropdown 1's value. Right?

Comment: Everything is working fine perfectly.. Thank you very much for giving a kind help to me..

Comment: multiple events in the sense handling click of one and then inside that event handling another event!! Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Comment: you toooooooo..... You are a perfect jscript coder. If you don't mind fetch me some blogs or sites you are following.. I have blanks in my jscript and jquery knowledge.

Comment: in youtube you can search for kudvenkat!! I prefer his tutorials in learning any latest technologies if it is available!! Well he has provided jQuery and javascript tutorials!!

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var $leave_type = "";
              $('.dropdown-inverse0 li > a').click(function () {
                     $leave_type = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute0");
                    if (typeof $leave_type === 'undefined') {
                        alert("Empty");
                    } else {
                        alert("Not Empty");
                    }
                });
              $('.dropdown-inverse1 li > a').click(function () {
                    var $person_id = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute1");
                  if (typeof $leave_type === 'undefined') {
                    if (typeof $person_id === 'undefined') {
                        alert($leave_type);
                    } else {
                       alert("Not Empty");
                    }
                  }else{
                      $('#menu0').trigger('click');
                      alert("Please select Leave Type");
                  }
                });
            });
```

Heeeyyyy try thiss......

Comment: :( give me some minuts ok?

Comment: Thanks.. it is not what exactly I want.. Still working fine.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lots of kind people tried to help me. Thank you for that. As they say best thing is to use bootstrap select but I wanted to use *ul li* bootstrap dropdown. So if any one interested in that. I found this.

```js
 $('document').ready(function () {

                $('.dropdown-inverse1 li > a').click(function () {
                    $(".btn1").text($(this).text());
                });
                $('.dropdown-inverse2 li > a').click(function () {
                    $(".btn2").text($(this).text());
                    var s = $(".btn1").text();
                    if(!(s=='HTML' ||  s=='CSS' ||  s=='JavaScript') ){
                     alert("Empty");
                    } 
                });
            });
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn1 btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Button1
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse1">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br/>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn2 btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Button2
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-inverse2">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```